# Task Scheduler with C# DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, datetimepicker

I am looking for a possibility to connect the C# `DateTimePicker` with the 
Task Scheduler Library. Looking through the documentation didn't enlighten 
my mind. Does anybody have or found a solution for this kind of matter?

Normally it is initialized by:

```
new TaskService().AddTask
("ITW Backup", new TaskTriggerType { Once }, 
new  ExecAction("Backup.exe", "C:\\Backup\\ini.ini", null));
```

But even the `{once}` statement out of the documentation is giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple :)

```
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        TaskService ts = new TaskService();
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        Trigger t = new TimeTrigger();
        t.StartBoundary = System.DateTime.Now.Date +this.dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay;
        td.Triggers.Add(t);
        //string path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string path1 = Desktop + @"\Desktop\Release\ITWBackup.exe";
        td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(path1, null, null));
        ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("ITWBackup", td);
        ts.BeginInit();
```